# How to make a child thread sleep without freezing UI thread in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep

I have a WPF application and I have individual threads running to accomplish tasks and I would like to have the current thread to go to sleep something like,

> Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(10000)

I do see it in Java but not in C#. I do know that I only have only one UI thread, so if I use Thread.Sleep(10000) my UI thread will be block. I am using async and await from .NET 4.5.

> var words = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
>   StringMgr.TextToUniqueWords(File.ReadAllText(filename));
>
> // I want to be able to sleep this thread for 10 seconds, without the UI freezing
>
> });

So how do I put a child thread to sleep without freezing the UI thread in a WPF application?

Thanks!

Comment: why are you wanting to do this? do you want something like a timer, which fires every eg 10seconds and queries the other exeucting threads if they are still running? or do you want to wait until they are completed (to do something other after completion)? I don't get why you want to wait inside the `StartNew`-call instead of simply writing subsequent code after the `await`-command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it? `Sleeping thread inside a Task won't freeze your GUI` but it will make the current background thread to go in sleep mode and your UI will remain responsive always -

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000000); // this line won't make UI freeze.
            });
        Thread.Sleep(5000000); // But this will certainly do.
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that you are not allowed to interact with the GUI inside the new Task.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're already using `async`, you can just do it the asynchronous way:

```
var words = await Task.Run(async () =>
{
  StringMgr.TextToUniqueWords(File.ReadAllText(filename));
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
});
```

However, I suspect that sleeping is the wrong solution for the actual problem you're trying to solve. If you'd like to post another question with your actual problem, you may find a better solution.